# Can decarboxylation of carboxylic acids be effected by bases other than soda lime?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds

What about other bases such as Group 1 or Group 2 hydroxides? Does it have to do something with the mechanism?

I don't understand the mechanism either:

[image]

What is NaOH supposed to with the acetate ion? I thought the acetate ion would be produced when NaOH reacted with acetic acid after which the reaction would proceed as follows:

[image: Mechanism of decarboxylation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decarboxylation can be effected by pretty much any base strong enough to produce the anion plus a high enough temperature. I've used DBU to effect an aromatic decarboxylation.
The role of the $\ce{NaOH}$ is this reaction is to capture the $\ce{CO2}$ as sodium carbonate.

Comment: So does NaOH act as a protonic acid over here (by donating H+ to the alkyle anion) and then capture the CO2 as Na2CO3? If yes, then isn't that quite odd that NaOH donates a proton?

Comment: Draw out the whole equation. 2NaOH + CO2 gives Na2CO3 + H2O which provides your proton source

Comment: Yes, I understand.